# how to Create dynamic input form which is able to store the array in mongodb?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

This is my mongoose schema

```
var VoSchema =new Schema({
  name:{type: String, 
  required: true},
  price:{type: String},
  feeds : [Schema.Types.Mixed]
 }, {strict: false});
```

**Dynamic input field**

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in inputs">
<div>
      <input ng-model="item.description">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input ng-model="item.qty">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input ng-model="item.cost"/>
    </div>
    <div >
      {{item.cost * item.qty}}
    </div>
  </div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href ng-click="addfield()" >[+]</a>
</div>
```

**controller for angularjs**

```
$scope.submitx = function(inv){
      $scope.inv.feeds = $scope.inputs.item
        console.log(inv);

            PostBlog.createInvoice(inv).then(function(data){
          console.log(data);
        });
            $scope.inv= {};
      }

   $scope.inputs = [];
   $scope.addfield=function(){
    $scope.inputs.push({ qty:0, cost:0, description:"" })
 }
```

I want to push the data in array to mongodb, how can i achieve this? 
please explain if possible in detail? how to use dynamic form in mean stack.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? its not clear. Please edit your question to make it more understandable

Comment: I am making an input form, with dynamic field. When user clicks add button, input field appears in which u can enter colleagues name. I wam to store this dynamic input field in mongodb

Comment: so you want to store those values in mongodb, right?

Comment: yes, but i guess i used for loop instead of any method, since its js